# Como exibir um alert e limpar campos com asp classico?

Tags: asp

Como faço para exibir um alert e limpar os campos textbox em asp classico ?
Estou começando a mexer com asp classico agora, estou perdido, só sei asp.net.
Consigo usar algo de asp.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como exibir um alert ou limpar controles com asp, utilize javascript para isso. O máximo que você pode fazer é inserir o código javascript na página com asp, mais ou menos assim:

```
<% response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Olá, fui criado com asp!');</script>") %>
```

Para limpar um textbox:

```
<% response.write("<script language=""javascript"">document.getElementById('meutextbox').value = ''</script>") %>
```

Se quiser limpar todos os textboxes da página, pode criar uma função javascript assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function limparTextboxes() {
        var textboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
            if(textboxes[i].getAttribute("type") == "text")
                textboxes[i].value = "";
        }           
    }
</script>
```

E chamá-la com asp assim:

```
<% Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">limparTextboxes();</script>") %>
```